# STM32G0 Interrupt bouncing

Tags: c, embedded, stm32, stm32cubeide

I wrote a handler for my keypad. Whenever press a button on keypad my board will interrupt but I think I have an bouncing problem.

I have a 4 x SSD, when I press the button, all 4 digits are going to same number. When I try on debugging mode, everything is okay.

How can I fix this? I wrote some delays but it still not working. I am using 4x4 keypad but I am just using 4x3 with 3 input, 4 output pins.

This is my IRQHandler :

```
/* Interrupt Handler */
void EXTI4_15_IRQHandler(void){
    /* keypad press from C1 */
            KeypadAllRows_RESET();
    GPIOB->ODR |= (1U << 0);        //Row4
    if((GPIOB->IDR & (1U << 5)) == (1U << 5)) //2
        KeyPress = 0;

    KeypadAllRows_RESET();
    GPIOA->ODR |= (1U << 8);       //Row1
    if((GPIOB->IDR & (1U << 4)) == (1U << 4)) //1
        KeyPress = 1;

    if((GPIOB->IDR & (1U << 5)) == (1U << 5)) //2
            KeyPress = 2;

    if((GPIOB->IDR & (1U << 9)) == (1U << 9)) //3
        KeyPress = 3;

    KeypadAllRows_RESET();
    GPIOB->ODR |= (1U << 8);       //Row2
    if((GPIOB->IDR & (1U << 4)) == (1U << 4)) //4
        KeyPress = 4;

    if((GPIOB->IDR & (1U << 5)) == (1U << 5)) //5
        KeyPress = 5;

    if((GPIOB->IDR & (1U << 9)) == (1U << 9)) //6
        KeyPress = 6;

    KeypadAllRows_RESET();
    GPIOB->ODR |= (1U << 2);       //Row3
    if((GPIOB->IDR & (1U << 4)) == (1U << 4)) //7
        KeyPress = 7;

    if((GPIOB->IDR & (1U << 5)) == (1U << 5)) //8
        KeyPress = 8;

    if((GPIOB->IDR & (1U << 9)) == (1U << 9)) //9
        KeyPress = 9;


    SSD_Digit1 = SSD_Digit2;
    SSD_Digit2 = SSD_Digit3;
    SSD_Digit3 = SSD_Digit4;
    SSD_Digit4 = KeyPress;

    EXTI->RPR1 |= (1U << 4);
    EXTI->RPR1 |= (1U << 5);
    EXTI->RPR1 |= (1U << 9);
    KeypadAllRows_SET();
```

And also this is my Loop , ( I think my loop is okay ) :

```
SSD_Close();
GPIOA->ODR |= (1U <<  7); //D4
SSD_SET(SSD_Digit4);
delay(200);

SSD_Close();
GPIOB->ODR |= (1U <<  7); //D3
SSD_SET(SSD_Digit3);
delay(200);

SSD_Close();
GPIOA->ODR |= (1U << 15); //D2
SSD_SET(SSD_Digit2);
delay(200);

SSD_Close();
GPIOA->ODR |= (1U <<  9); //D1
SSD_SET(SSD_Digit1);
delay(200);
```

I Edited the code,

*Delays in Handler are removed.

*Row3 is working. But another numbers are not working well. The row I wrote at the bottom in the Handler only works properly. When I click on the numbers in the other Rows, the digits of all SSDs become the same number.

Comment: It's very hard to tell what this code is meant to do. Calling delay routines in an ISR is generally a terrible idea. Are the variables you modify in the ISR defined as volatile?

Comment: "4 x SSD" - what is SSD and acronym for?

Comment: yes, all of them are volatile.

Comment: SSD = 7 segment display, I assume.

Comment: And this is why we don't invent new TLA.

Comment: Actually this algorithm is nonsense.  You already have to set the row output in order to, to detect a bottom on the column inputs, so it is entirely synchronous. You simply read the columns at the time you set the row.  It is entirely synchronous, no EXTI or denounce should be required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure it out what was the problem. Problem is in Handler.

```
EXTI->RPR1 |= (1U << 4);
EXTI->RPR1 |= (1U << 5);
EXTI->RPR1 |= (1U << 9);
KeypadAllRows_SET();
```

This part is the causing SSD problem. I should resetting flags after the resetting ROWs.

```
KeypadAllRows_SET();
EXTI->RPR1 |= (1U << 4);
EXTI->RPR1 |= (1U << 5);
EXTI->RPR1 |= (1U << 9);
```

So, this is the edited handler.

Thanks for all answers and helpful informations about interrupts and timers.

Answer (score 3):

Don't put delays in an ISR!  Your delays seem a bit scatter-gin in any case.  Using an ISR in this manner is probably inappropriate.  I am not sure that "fixing" your solution is productive - you would do better with a different solution.

Button presses are slow enough to scan periodically rather then on EXTI.  That will make de-bouncing easier, because the scan rate can simply be longer than the bounce time - 50ms will be plenty.  You could do that in a timer ISR or an periodic thread if you are using an RTOS.

If you insist on doing it this way, then on the ISR you could:

- Disable the EXTI, start a timer and on timer expiry (in the Timer ISR), re-enable the EXTI and  disable the timer.
- Timestamp the initial EXTI, then ignore any subsequent EXTI within say say 50ms.

As you can see both are unnecessarily complicated.

Ultimately, the key scan is necessarily periodic, so any EXTI interrupt here is caused by the setting of the row-select AND-ed with a button press so is entirely synchronous with the row select, so using an EXTI serves no purpose, simply read the columns when you set the row select.

Comment: I am new in stm32 so I am trying to do some projects to improve myself. I am practising interrupts, that's why I used EXTI on keypad. 

In this code I want to detect my button presses with EXTI and than I want to light up my 4 digit SSD like " 3 -> 34 -> 347 -> 3479 -> 4792 "

Comment: Polling all buttons repeatedly from inside a cyclic timer interrupt is standard procedure and good practice. As for locking up hardware timers, you just need 1 which you can wrap a HAL around and use for all non-critical tasks (millisecond accuracy or higher).

Comment: I want to ask a question about the my code. If I press "0" on keypad, code works very well, but when I try another numbers all my digits on SSD become a same number. Can you understand why ?

Comment: @AnatolianPerseus Like Clifford says, all the delays in the code doesn't make sense and you can't hope to salvage this code. You need to study how to use hardware timers. Also don't connect buttons/switches to a flank triggered interrupt in case you are a beginner. It's rather complicated to do that correctly.

Comment: Starting and disabling the inrrupts in the handlers is an overkill. @Lundin way is the correct way of doing it

Comment: @AnatolianPerseus I suggest you think of a more appropriate exercise to explore EXTI. You can still explore interrupts using a timer.